# How can I loop over files in a directory and move only the unique files using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, jinja2

I’m trying to loop over all files in a directory, these files are named differently but should have the same contents. Is there a way to loop through all these files using ansible and then move the unique files into a different directory.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can ask the *find* module to calculate a checksum. For example, given the files

```bash
shell> tree dir1
dir1
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── c.txt
├── d.txt
├── e.txt
└── f.txt
```

and their's content

```bash
shell> find dir1 -type f | sort | xargs cat
123
123
456
789
789
789
```

the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    dir1: "{{ playbook_dir }}/dir1"
    dir2: "{{ playbook_dir }}/dir2"
    files_unique: "{{ out.files|groupby('checksum')|
                                map(attribute='1.0.path')|
                                list }}"

  tasks:

    - find:
        paths: "{{ dir1 }}"
        file_type: file
        get_checksum: true
      register: out

    - debug:
        var: files_unique

    - copy:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dest: "{{ dir2 }}"
      loop: "{{ files_unique }}"
```

copies the unique files from the directory *dir1* to the directory *dir2*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [find] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  files_unique:
  - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-033/dir1/a.txt
  - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-033/dir1/d.txt
  - /export/scratch/tmp7/test-033/dir1/c.txt

TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-033/dir1/a.txt)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-033/dir1/d.txt)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/export/scratch/tmp7/test-033/dir1/c.txt)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```bash
shell> tree dir2
dir2
├── a.txt
├── c.txt
└── d.txt
```